# While loop for integers with user input

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I just started programming on UNIX this week and one of my homework task is to create a script that reads positive numbers until -99 is entered and negative numbers show an error ( 0 to -98). This is what I've come up with but kinda stuck. thanks :)

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=1

echo "Enter a positive integer number (-99 to quit):"
read NUMBER

echo "$NUMBER: "
while [ $NUMBER -ge $COUNTER ]; do
    echo $COUNTER
    ((COUNTER++))
done
```

Comment: Can you reword your assignment?  "reads positive numbers until -99 is entered and negative numbers show an error ( 0 to -98). "  That isn't very clear to me.

Comment: Like a python script? Entering valid values until quit. so -99 is quit and negative numbers are errors :9

Comment: What is the `COUNTER` for then?  That is not explained by this assignment.  Do the positive numbers have to be in order?  Can they not be entered twice...with your `COUNTER` if a person entered `5` it would work and then if they entered `2` it would not, but `2` is a valid positive integer no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
#! /bin/bash -

read -p "Enter a positive integer (-99 to quit): " USR_INT

while [[ -n "$USR_INT" ]]; do

    case "$USR_INT" in
        -99)
            echo "Exiting..."
            exit 0
            ;;
        -*)
            echo "Error, please enter a positive integer."
            exit 1
            ;;
        0)
            echo "Error, please enter a positive integer."
            exit 1
            ;;
        [0-9]*)
            echo "You have entered $USR_INT"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Error, please enter a positive integer."
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac

    read -p "Enter a positive integer (-99 to quit): " USR_INT

done
```

Comment: how would I keep script running if I entered a negative number? :o

Comment: Remove the `Exit 1` line under the `-*)` part, however you said a negative number should generate an error.

Comment: another question! what does the asterisk do?

Comment: It's a wildcard:  "Matches any string, including the null string. When the globstar shell option is enabled, and ‘*’ is used in a filename expansion context, two adjacent ‘*’s used as a single pattern will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a ‘/’, two adjacent ‘*’s will match only directories and subdirectories."

See bash reference manual:
[3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching] &
[3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs]

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -p 'Number (-99 to quit): '

    if ! [[ "$REPLY" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then echo 'Error: Not an integer' >&2
    elif (( REPLY == -99 ));           then break
    elif (( REPLY <= 0   ));           then echo 'Error: Need positive integers >0' >&2
    else
        printf 'Got "%d", that is number %d\n' "$REPLY" "$(( ++c ))"
    fi
done
```

This is an infinite loop that is exited when the user enters `-99`. Any positive integer response will prompt the code to say `Got "some number"` followed by how many valid numbers read so far, whereas a negative integer, zero, or a non-numeric input will give a diagnostic message on standard error. The code uses the variable `REPLY` which is the variable written to by `read` if not given any other variable name.

The test for correct numeric input is done with matching the response against the regular expression `^-?[0-9]+$`.  This expression will *match* if the response is on the form that we expect (an optional dash followed by at least one digit). If it doesn't match, a diagnostic message is issued on standard error.

Up until the first `elif` we can not be sure that `$REPLY` is an integer. After that, we use `(( ... ))` for arithmetic evaluation of the comparisons.

The test for `-99` needs to come before the test for negative integers, as we otherwise would not have any way of exiting the loop.

Comment: thanks for this informative post! still learning, used to python indentation ahaha

Comment: @WickdLotus You can break and indent the lines after each `then` if you wish. I just wanted it to be compact. I wouldn't know Python if it jumped up and bit me in the nose.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple:

```
!/bin/bash

while :
do
   echo "Enter a positive integer number (-99 to quit):"
   read NUMBER

   if (( NUMBER == -99 ))
   then
      exit
   fi

   echo "$NUMBER: "

   COUNTER=1
   while (( COUNTER <= NUMBER ))
   do
       echo $COUNTER
       ((COUNTER++))
   done
done
```